# Jitsi meet external api how properly configure it audio only and auto join?

Tags: javascript, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I want to set up jitsi meet room, where users auto join the room, the username and room will be generated for the user when the page with iframe is loaded, and I want the room be audio only.

I was looking to config files and found couple properties which should make jitsi audio only, but event when I set them, I still see video button there. Here is my whole set up.
I could not find any property to auto join the room :(

Here is the code I used to audio only which does not work for me

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
<script src='https://meet.jit.si/external_api.js'></script>

<script>
function init(){

const domain = 'meet.jit.si';
const options = {
    roomName: 'JitsiMeetAPIExample',
    width: 700,
    height: 700,
        userInfo: {
        email: 'email@jitsiexamplemail.com',
        displayName: 'John Doe'
    },
    parentNode: document.querySelector('.meet'),
        configOverwrite: { startAudioOnly: true, TOOLBAR_BUTTONS: [], TOOLBAR_ALWAYS_VISIBLE: false },
        interfaceConfigOverwrite: { startAudioOnly: true, TOOLBAR_BUTTONS: [], TOOLBAR_ALWAYS_VISIBLE: false },
};
const api = new JitsiMeetExternalAPI(domain, options);
}

</script>
    </head>
    <body class="meet" onload='init()'>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add jquery CDN first

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
```

Start Only works in config not in interface

```
configOverwrite: { startAudioOnly: true }
```

See details on
[jitsi](https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/dev-guide/dev-guide-iframe)